# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setThemingColor' of null

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm writing an extension for the Forge Viewer and I ran into this problem when trying to use the setThemingColor() method in the "load" part of the extension:

```
function extensaoteste(viewer, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
  }

  extensaoteste.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);
  extensaoteste.prototype.constructor = extensaoteste;

extensaoteste.prototype.load = function() {
    this.onSelectionBinded = this.onSelectionEvent.bind(this);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, this.onSelectionBinded);

    this.viewer.setThemingColor(3554,new THREE.Vector4(255/255, 255/255, 102/255, 1));
```

The code goes on, but the rest works fine. As you can see, there is another part of the extension, with an event listener.

If I use the exact same line with the *setThemingColor* method in the *extensaoteste.prototype.onSelectionEvent*, it works perfectly. I understand it is the ***this.viewer*** part that isn't returning anything, however it works in the line above.

I have used the code from https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/events/#step-2-listen-and-react-to-an-event as a template.

I know this is probably a silly question, but I really can't understand it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the model geometry was not fully loaded when the call was made to set color and the null reference was not called out on `this.viewer` but on the model object:

```
Viewer3D.prototype.setThemingColor = function(dbId, color, model, recursive) {
        // use default RenderModel by default
        model = model || this.model;

        model.setThemingColor(dbId, color, recursive); // null reference here

        // we changed the scene to apply theming => trigger re-render
        this.impl.invalidate(true);
    };
```

Try set color (and other fragment level operations) after the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is fired:

```
var viewer = this.viewer;
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,()=>viewer.setThemingColor(3554,new THREE.Vector4(255/255, 255/255, 102/255, 1));
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you very much!